# R get type of open plot device png or pdf

Tags: r

In R, I need to check what kind of plot device is currently open, e.g.:

```r
png("test.png"); get_dev_type()
# answer should be "png"
dev.off(); get_dev_type()
# answer should be "error: could not find open plot device"
pdf("test.pdf"); get_dev_type()
# answer should be "pdf"
dev.off()
plot(0); get_dev_type()
# answer should be "x11"
```

I could not figure this out with the `grDevices::dev.*` functions.

Thanks a lot for help,
Chris

Comment: Does `dev.cur()` not give you what you need? Maybe `names(dev.cur())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `names(dev.cur())`:

```r
get_dev_type <- function() names(dev.cur())

png("test.png")
get_dev_type()
#> [1] "png"

dev.off()
#> RStudioGD 
#>         2 

get_dev_type()
#> [1] "RStudioGD"

pdf("test.pdf")
get_dev_type()
#> [1] "pdf"

dev.off()
#> RStudioGD 
#>         2 
plot(0)
get_dev_type()
#> [1] "RStudioGD"
```